# How to use type predicates to give type to an value of type unknown?

Tags: typescript

I have a type predicate function that is expected to give type to a JSON object

```
interface Duck {
  canQuack: true
}

function isDuck(duck: unknown): duck is Duck {
  if (typeof duck !== "object" || ! duck) return false
  return duck.canQuack === true
}
```

But typescript complains that `canQuack` doesn't exit on `object`.

How do I do type check on an object with type `unknown`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the typescript documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates), they recommend casting to the the type and then checking the value. Just make sure the cast is safe, so that you don't get runtime errors (that's why we first check it's an object). In your case, the solution would be.

```
interface Duck {
  canQuack: true
}

function isDuck(duck: unknown): duck is Duck {
  // Check that the candidate is an object
  return duck != null && (typeof duck === 'object' || typeof duck === 'function') 
  // check that it has canQuack
    && (duck as Duck).canQuack === true;
}
```

**Edit**: made the object check actually work, copied the "is object" check from lodash https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L11745

Comment: This will be a runtime error if `duck = { test: 1}`, it is an object but `canQuack` is undefined.

Comment: It won't be, you can test in typescript playground. `const a = { test: 1 }; console.log(a.canQuack === true)` is perfectly valid javascript, using undefined properties of an object is fine, it will just give you `undefined`

Comment: After second thought I think this is the correct answer, since the official doc also do it that way. You do have to check for null though, since `typeof null === 'object'`, and can raise runtime error

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an additional type guard

```ts
interface Duck {
  canQuack: true;
}

function isDuck(duck: unknown): duck is Duck {
  if (typeof duck !== "object" || !duck) return false;
  const canQuackGuard = (o: object): o is { canQuack: unknown } =>
    "canQuack" in o;
  return (
    canQuackGuard(duck) &&
    typeof duck.canQuack === "boolean"
  );
}
```